# Divide self intersecting polygon (C Code)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

I want to divide a self-intersecting polygon into simple polygons. I have the edges and the intersection points saved in a data structure (a connected list).

So here is an example. I have a connected list with the x,y coordinates of the edges and the intersection points of the polygon. According to the polygon in this [picture](http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/1865/image004cm.jpg) it would be :: (1) -> (2) -> (3) ... -> (7). What I'm trying to do is to get the edges of the simple polygons (triangles here). In this case :: 1,2,7 / 3,4,5 / 5,6,7.

Comment: I suggest you flesh this question out a bit more, at least showing the data structure with an example and maybe what you have started.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that [Bentley-Ottman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) would be your best bet. There's a nice interactive visualization [here](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~bjlafren/segint/index.htm). Another nice description [here](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0108/algorithm_0108.htm).