# Split Self intersecting Polygon into non self intersecting polygon

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, split, polygon, area

I have a set of point which represent a self intersecting polygon.I am able to find the intersection point.But i am unable to split this polygon into smaller polygon which is not self intersection.Any idea how to do that.I am using vb 2008 .I need this to calculate the area of self intersecting polygon.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a bit known about this problem. In fact, there are earlier similar questions here on SO, e.g., "[Divide self intersecting polygon (C Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4115853/387778)."
Here is a Master's thesis on the topic: [PDF download link](http://www.cis.southalabama.edu/~hain/general/Theses/Subramaniam_thesis.pdf).

---

[image: Thesis fig]