# Make valid big geometry with POSTGIS operations

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Wanted to ask if anyone could help me with this problem.
The thing is that i have a big geometry, with `5,000,000` vertices and an space of `170MB`. That i want to store in a postgres database, after i apply the process of `ST_MakValid` (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html). The problem is that the process juts takes too long to finish. I ran

```
SELECT ST_MakeValid(geom) FROM myTable
```

for several hours and never ended. So wanted to check if someone knew a way to permorf this operation with a better perfomance.

Comment: Hi
Generally speaking, SQL interpreters are used to look up data quickly (after insert). Of course you could also manipulate data with some functions like add,sum or even concatenation. If you need a core computation, I'd suggest to us C/C++ with AVR instructions like here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179208/postgis-boostgeometry-c

Comment: you can try `buffer(geom,0)`. While it does "fix" some issues, it is not clear how it is done, so be sure to do some quality control after